# How can I use a plugin in ingress-nginx to wrap a request?

Tags: nginx, kubernetes, nginx-ingress

I'm trying to use the [lua-circuit-breaker](https://github.com/dream11/lua-circuit-breaker) plugin with [ingress-nginx](https://kubernetes.github.io/ingress-nginx/) in a Kubernetes cluster. I want to set up two upstream servers such that the first is "wrapped" with this circuit breaker, and it falls back to a different upstream endpoint in case the circuit breaker is open. Both upstream servers are Kubernetes `Service`s.

There are 2 things that I am unsure of at the moment.

1. The [plugin support](https://github.com/kubernetes/ingress-nginx/tree/main/rootfs/etc/nginx/lua/plugins) of ingress-nginx seems to expect plugins to operate within certain callbacks like `init_worker` or `rewrite`. I don't see how I can replicate the [example in the lua-circuit-breaker plugin](https://github.com/dream11/lua-circuit-breaker/blob/master/ngx_lua_sample/nginx.conf#L49) given that it sets up a local variable before the "wrapped" function and uses it after. As far as I know, I wouldn't be able to access the `cb` variable in the `header_filter` callback if I initialize it in the `rewrite` callback. It doesn't seem to be possible to wrap the request within the scope of the variable.
2. I am not sure how to use Kubernetes `Ingress` objects to set up the fallback behavior. If I use a `server-snippet` I believe that only applies to a single upstream server and I can't set up multiple upstream servers in a single Ingress.

I sort-of hit a wall here with lack of familiarity of `lua-nginx-module` that `ingress-nginx` uses. Any help is greatly appreciated!